# php/javascript application with HTML5

Tags: php, include

I'm developping an app (javascript and php). I use the include command at the top of my index, so it has becone [www.mypage.php] .

now I'm wondering if that in compatible with HTML5 ?

**EDIT**

ok i have not use HTML5 yet but just wondering coz i will in future.

my index:

```
<?php 
include_once("../config.php"); 
?>
<html>
<head>
.
.
.
```

so its url should be www.mypage.php instead of www.mypage.html

Would that make any conflict when using HTML5 ?

Comment: If I understand what your saying yes, do you have a bit of code to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How could a PHP include() be compatible or not compatible with HTM5?
Since PHP runs server-side, and then sends some content back to the browser, the browser never knows how that content was generated.
Your question is not relevant.

Comment: Go to your webpage, and select "View source" in your browser. You'll see it NEVER displays PHP code, because PHP is executed by the webserver before the page is sent to your browser. So, your PHP script may generate any content your browser is able to display: HTML1, HTML2, HTML3, HTML4, HTML5, XML, XHTML, plain text, image file...

Answer (score 0):

include does not change any file name just implements the logic to the said file . php will always be compatible with html since it has large active userbase .

you have probably done some mistake

research more on php a file with .php extension runs html fine you should not get any error

since i think you have  a page with .html extension hence php code will not run then then just

```
      simple just save your file has .php not with html extension
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language so basically php gets run on the server what gets seen on the webpage is the output of the php code, that's why when you pull up the source code of a website you can't see any php code (no `<?php`or `?>`).

So to answer your question, there should be no compatibility issues, but, to clarify the php commands: 
`include()` and `include_once` do not change the page name... It only includes a file into the php file that gets loaded (in your case it loads config.php), it is however important that the file with the `include` or `include_once` has the file ending .php and not .html.

Here is the php documentation on include_once() and include:

**include_once():** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

**include():** http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Hope this helps you understand php a bit better :)